# How to make matlab help pop up in extra window?

Tags: matlab

If I use the 'help' command in the matlab command window, the output will also pop up in the command window. Is there a way to make it pop up in a separate window?
Only way I found is to use 'help' from the UI and then dock it somewhere. But the help text that pops up in that case is not exactly the same and takes up more space..
Cheers,
frommage

Comment: You could use `doc`instead of `help`, see: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/doc.html

Comment: What you really want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use evalc to redirect command window output to a variable instead:

```
A = evalc('help mean');
```

Then maybe use msgbox to display in a new window?

```
msgbox(A);
```

Probably not exactly a full solution, since there is some html in the 'help' output and msgbox doesn't process the html, but only displays it as text.

Comment: Tricky! You are addressing the issue that `help mean` has different output than `doc mean`. I like it.